# Vue 2.0 server-side-render with template inside #app container

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering

Server side rendering page for reference: [ssr.html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)

Now the problem, what if we want to define template inside the `<div id="app"></div>` in html file itself, not in Vue instance template property? Like this:

```
<div id="app">You have been here for {{ counter }} seconds.</div>
```

In this case if we want to pre-render it, we will get next pre-rendered html:

```
<div id="app" server-rendered="true">You have been here for 0 seconds&period;</div>
```

And here is the conflict problem. If we will output pre-rendered html, we lose our template and Vue doesn't know where to output counter inside our `<div id="app">`.

Is it possible somehow to provide template inside `<div id="app"></div>` container and in the same time pre-render it? Or provide template near the pre-rendered in html(so Vue will know that here is pre-rendered and here is template and i will use it if any changes happens in the model)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible somehow to provide template inside  container and in the same time pre-render it? Or

Short but complete answer: No. For Vue SSR, you cannot use in-DOM templates. You have to use string-based templates (including Single File Components).

Comment: I think i found workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/avonxe6m/ but this is single file without components. Not sure is it possible to do the same with components.